# Not able to ping the host machine (or any other machine on the network) from the linux docker container

Tags: docker, ping, windows-firewall

I am using Docker Desktop Version 2.0.0.3 (31259) on my windows server 2016 machine. From the host machine(say A), I can ping to any other machine in the network(say B), but when I run a linux container inside my machine A, I am neither able to ping machine A nor machine B.
I also used wireshark to monitor the incoming traffic on the machine but I cannot find any entry for this. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

So how can I proceed further so that I can ping machines A or B from my docker container.

The ping error I get is like this

> PING ***.***.**.171 (**.**.**.171) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> \From 192.168.65.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
>
> From 192.168.65.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: Can you give us an example line, how you start the docker container? As I remember you would need to explicitly add the container to the host network to reach the host on it's outer IP address.

Comment: @chrisl  So I used this command to run container from my image, docker run -it -d --privileged mycontainer:version1 /usr/sbin/init